# How to convert String to dateTime using dataweave Mule?

Tags: java, string, datetime, mule

I want to convert `2012-12-26` to a date time format, for this I used the following code into a dataweave:

```
("2012-12-26"++ "T00:00:00.000+00:00") as :datetime {class:"java.util.Calendar", format : "YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"}
```

But it doesn't work, I got the following exception:

`Cannot coerce a :string to a :datetime, caused by :Text '2012-12-13T00:00:00.000+00:00' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain ZonedDateTime from TemporalAccessor: DateTimeBuilder[fields=
{WeekBasedYear[WeekFields[SUNDAY,1]]=2012, MonthOfYear=12, DayOfYear=13, OffsetSeconds=0}
, ISO, null, null, 00:00], type org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeBuilder`

Any idea guys?

Comment: `2012-12-2600:00:00.000+00:00` is missing the `T` between the day and the hour as defined in `YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX`

Comment: @bradimus , I added `T` , now i got this : 

`Cannot coerce a :string to a :datetime, caused by :Text '2012-12-13T00:00:00.000+00:00' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain ZonedDateTime from TemporalAccessor: DateTimeBuilder[fields=
{WeekBasedYear[WeekFields[SUNDAY,1]]=2012, MonthOfYear=12, DayOfYear=13, OffsetSeconds=0}
, ISO, null, null, 00:00], type org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeBuilder.`

Comment: You probably want `dd`, not `DD`. `DD` is day of year. `dd` is day of month. Take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: @bradimus , i changed `DD` to `dd` but i have the same exception `Unable to obtain ZonedDateTime from TemporalAccessor: DateTimeBuilder[fields= {WeekBasedYear[WeekFields[SUNDAY,1]]=2012, MonthOfYear=12, DayOfYear=13, OffsetSeconds=0} , ISO, null, null, 00:00], type org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeBuilder.`

Comment: Try lowercase `yyyy` and lowercase `dd` in the format. Uppercase `YYYY` is weekbased year, and @bradimus already explained `DD`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

`datetime: ("2017-03-02T00:00:00.000Z" replace "Z" with "+0700") as :datetime{format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"}`